# Angular 7 - Passing data to child component properly

Tags: angular

I am trying to generate 3 Google Charts using a for loop. Each Google Chart should show different data in the Pie Chart.

For that to happen, I embedded the Google Chart inside a child component that takes some input variables from the parent and renders the chart.

I noticed that all 3 charts are showing only the last data passed instead of showing a different chart for each set of data. What am I doing wrong here?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k8pb1u)

**app.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let result of results; index as i;">
    <app-google-chart #chart{{i}} 
    [title]="title"
    [type]="type"
    [data]="data"
    [columnNames]="columnNames"
    [options]="options"
    [width]="width"
    [height]="height">

    </app-google-chart>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  results = ["1","2","3"];

  title;
  type;
  data;
  columnNames;
  options;
  width;
  height;

  ngOnInit() {

    for(let i=0;i<this.results.length;i++)
    {
      this.drawChart(i);
    }
  }

  drawChart(index:any) {
    var passed;
    var failed;

   if(index == 0) 
    {
      passed=50;
      failed=50;
    }
    else if(index == 1) 
    {
      passed=20;
      failed=30;
    }
    else if(index == 2) 
    {
      passed=40;
      failed=60;
    }
    this.title = "Chart" + index;
    this.type = "PieChart";
    this.data = [['Pass', passed], ['Fail', failed]];

  }
}
```

Comment: `[data]="data"`: you're passing the same `AppComponent.data` to every chart. Your TypeScript code doesn't make much sense: you're overwriting the same instance variables at each iteration of the loop. If you want three different data in the component, you need an array of 3 elements.

Comment: hmm.. I am not sure how to fix my typescript code to pass unique values to the child component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your `app.component.ts` you are calling the same function `drawChart(index)` with different values to replace the same values.

so the only last iteration exists.
Check this out
[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k9hn8q)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Forgot to fork your stackblitz, So changes didn't reflect.
Now check the link.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of updating the same variables, you can push the properties to your `results` array and use it's properties in your html

```html
<div *ngFor="let result of results; index as i;">
    <app-google-chart #chart{{i}} 
    [title]="result.title"
    [type]="result.type"
    [data]="result.data"
    [columnNames]="columnNames"
    [options]="options"
    [width]="width"
    [height]="height">

    </app-google-chart>
</div>
```

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  // or a different set of data to be looped through in OnInit
  dataLength = 3;

  // data to be passed to children component
  results = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    for(let i = 0;i < dataLength; i++) {
      this.results.push(this.drawChart(i));
    }
  }

  drawChart(index:any) {
    var passed;
    var failed;

   if(index == 0) {
      passed=50;
      failed=50;
    } else if(index == 1) {
      passed=20;
      failed=30;
    } else if(index == 2) {
      passed=40;
      failed=60;
    }

    // instead of this
    this.title = "Chart" + index;
    this.type = "PieChart";
    this.data = [['Pass', passed], ['Fail', failed]];

    return { 
       title: 'Chart' + index,
       type: 'PieChart',
       data: [['Pass', passed], ['Fail', failed]]
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't work. The size of results in `ngOnInit` is 0.
results will remain empty.

Comment: @KautilyaKatiha you're right, I completely missed that. I updated my answer